ggmap using multiple column data
I'm trying to map multiple columns of data on one map. I'm guessing I need to use reshape or something similar but struggling to find a way. My data looks like this
Data Example
I created the map in GetStadia and it works fine for individual column data but if I want to overlay multiple columns on one map I fail. I have maybe 8 or 9 columns that I would like to be able to lay over each other in different configurations. This is each column individually
Male
Female
Created like this:
ggmap(Mpanga)+
geom_point(data = cycad, aes(x=Longitude,y=Latitude, size = Males), colour = "506", alpha = .3)+
scale_size_continuous(name="Males",  breaks = c(1,5,10,20), range=c(1, 12))
Thanks for the help
